# Impact Flow Tracking for feature updates & changes

Tags: test-management, qa-developer, regression-testing, programmer-relations, requirements-engineering

I have been working in a startup as a manual and automation QA engineer. New features gets applied to our site every 2 weeks. Whenever a redesign project comes up, such as a product page redesign, we keep forgetting to handle all the other numerous features that were implemented in the last few years. People who implemented those features have often moved out of the team, and details are forgotten. This is usually happening with minor features.

I was searching for ideas on how to keep track of all the features in the website. Ideally, when we add a new requirement, we should be able to easily identify the impact of the new project on existing ones.

I tried using Excel to create a trace of every field in a feature to its impact on different parts of the website. Is this the correct way to approach tracing? It has been very time consuming, and we don't have a good template.

Answer (score 1):

```
we keep forgetting to handle all the numerous features
which were implemented in last few years.
```

I think this is the the key to your problems and leads me to suggest focusing on a lot of different areas to improve the situation:

- A comprehensive set of unit, integrated and user-acceptance tests of all functionality
- Good multi-media documentation with standards and a searchable index
- A good bug tracking system, e.g. jira, pivotal tracker, etc. also searchable
- Good code review and workflow system such as github
- Code linting and grading

I don't think the grid of what affects what approach you are considering will scale or be maintained correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should follow tracability matrix and always add new requirements/Features to same matrix so old will be there as record and also you will be able to track new.

As a tool Excel is fine as start level but I would suggest to use [TFS](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/tfs-overview-vs.aspx) to log all old and coming requirements. It will allow you to maintain all requirements/Features history in very good way. TFS is easy to manage.

Comment: Tractability matrix will help me to track old  & new feature which will be added,i wish to track the changes need to be made,if at one particular point any feature is changed or improved its impact will be on several other feature directly or indirectly in different pages , so what is the best possible way to track these effect. consider the core sr.developer not present to guide the jr or the newly joined developer,

Comment: That thing you can do via TFS.

Comment: it will be very beneficial if you provide me with an example

Answer (score 0):

from my understandings you have SRS of any web based product, when product released the SRS will be updated so follow these steps

```
1. get updated SRS document from Project Management Team.
2.create an excel containing UI and fuctionality of each page.
```

this way you can maintain it, in short maintain your SRS it will be easier.